# Symfony/Doctrine get entries count by day on a datetime field

Tags: mysql, symfony, date, datetime, doctrine-orm

Let's assume we have a Symfony entity, containing an `id` (int), `title` (string) and `created` (datetime) field.

I need now a count by days, something like

```
day, amount
2015-11-22, 5
2015-11-23, 2
2015-11-24, 0
```

Currently I'm just loading all entries (for the current month), loop them in PHP and call `format('Y-m-d')` on the datetime filed to get the day, then I store that one in an array containing the day as key and the amount as value (if the day is in the array, just increase by 1, otherwise set value to 1).

There has to be a better way, I'm pretty sure, that I should be able to calculate it directly on the db.

With plain sql I would do something like

```
SELECT DATE(created) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS amount 
FROM testtable 
GROUP BY DATE(created)
```

*Edit: Since the query will use `COUNT()` on the id, which is the primary key and through that unique it wouldn't need a `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` here, a `COUNT(id)` would produce exact the same result. If I would perform the count on the title however and I would like to only count unique titles, then it would need the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `COUNT()`, just if someone's wondering.*

But how can I do this with Symfony/Doctrine?

Comment: May I ask, what that downvote was for? If the question isn't written well, please tell me, or do an edit, I can't see, why this isn't a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, and hope, this helps someone else with a similar problem.

First of all, `Doctrine` doesn't have a `Date` function, since not all DB systems support `Date` natively. Doctrine is build to be able to work with all major DB systems out there, so no natively `Date` here.

To add a date function for MySQL (not sure about other DBs) we can create a new class let's call it `DQLDate`. Mine looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\BarBundle\DQL;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker,
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser,
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * Extracts the date form a timestamp (Mysql function)
 * DQLDate :: DATE ( date as Y-m-d )
 */
class DQLDate extends FunctionNode 
{

    protected $date;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker) 
    {
       return 'DATE(' . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) .')';
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser) 
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

Next we need to register that function in our `config.yml` file.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        ...
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                DATE: Foo\BarBundle\DQL\DQLDate
```

And then we're all set.

If we assume the SQL query

```
SELECT DATE(created) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS amount 
FROM testtable 
GROUP BY DATE(created)
```

We can now transform this to

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('DATE(e.created) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS amount')
    ->from('FooBarBundle:TestTable', 'e')
    ->groupBy('day');
$result = $q->getQuery()->getResult();
```

As mentioned in the question, the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `COUNT` isn't necessary, if the field is unique. If we would count the titles for example and we would want to know how many different titles there are, then we'd need the `DISTINCT` keyword.